# how to test geolocation on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation

I'm starting with geocoding, and after read a few things I realize that are some people using the simulator for testing their code.

Is that possible!?? Can someone tell which tools use!?
(it's better than walking around)

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 now supports `"Location simulation"`, you can refer it [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/).

Steps to use this feature:

1. Build & run your app in `iPhone 5.0 Simular`.
2. At the top menu bar, you'll find `Debug` -> `Location` -> `Custom Location..`(or you can choose to use others).
3. Set the `Latitude` & `Longitude` for the location.

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 5 and Xcode 4.1 is is now possible to test location in the simulator, There are also premade classes for this such as : https://github.com/progrmr/CLLocationManager-simulator

Comment: Thank You! You give a good answer. But Kjuly solution is more comfortable to use.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kjuly's answer, if it throws error such as `"code":2` for me, then try to put instead of `Debug`->`Location`->`Custom location` the other option such as `Apple`, `City Run` etc. For me it dropped out the error and then you can turn back to `Custom location`.

Found this helpful on: [Geolocation is not working in iOS 8 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972819/geolocation-is-not-working-in-ios-8-simulator)