# Issues with Phonegap Geolocation on iOS 6 simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation

I'm getting a "kCLErrorDomain error 0" message when trying to use the geolocation plugin on the iPhone 6 simulators. My app seems to work fine with actual devices (including an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.0.2), but does not work on the simulator. Any ideas what the issue is? I'm not sure if it's an issue I'll see with certain version of iOS, I've only been able to test of iOS 7 and iOS 8.0.2

I am not using Phonegap Build, btw

Appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answers on this question should help you out.

[Geolocation is not working in iOS 8 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972819/geolocation-is-not-working-in-ios-8-simulator)

The key suggestion that did it for me was to go to the **Debug** menu for the iOS Simulator, then select **Location** and choose anything except **Custom Location...**.  You can leave it like this or go back and change it to a custom location after a few seconds.

My guess is that the simulator has a bug which defaults to a NULL custom location on the initial start-up, and doesn't actually get a value until you start changing options.